# Why are my channels generating straight lines?

Tags: qgis, rivers

I'm having a rather horrible issue where my rivers decide to be straight lines instead of following the DEM I am using. Can someone explain why this is happening, and what I can do to solve this problem aside from manually routing rivers?

UPDATE: Using a Low Pass Filter allowed expected channels to be created in the lower areas of the map, but prevented them from generating at higher elevations at all.

UPDATE 2: Due to GRASS's r.watersheds crashing QGIS when I try to use it, I am using SAGA's Channels tools.

Solution: r.watersheds can be run outside of QGIS using GRASS as a standalone program. This works on windows in spite of r.watershed hanging infinitely within QGIS.

[image: The problem I am having]

Comment: Sometimes integer DEMs give line generation a hard time. If you haven't tried using a low-pass filter to convert the DEM to float, you should probably do that first.

Comment: @Vince I just gave that a shot. It fixed the lower elevation areas but prevented higher elevations from generating channels at all. Is there any way I could hybridize two DEMs by a given region so I could use some of column A and some of column B to get the channels done everywhere?

Comment: You could certainly try, though I can't imagine why it would be necessary. What coefficients did you use for the filter? I've only tried 0.001x8+0.992.

Comment: @Vince The filter I used didn't have an option for that. Should I not be using SAGA's Simple Filter? I've resorted to simply manually correcting the errors by following terrain features and my elevation map. I'd love to save myself another day of work though...

Comment: The fact that you're using SAGA tools should be in the Question body. I'm not a QGIS/SAGA guy, so I can't provide any further input.

Comment: @Vince Oh, sorry! I'm very new to this. Updating.

Comment: Is the information in this of any help?  It looks like you should try some different minimum slopes.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374056/obtain-channel-stream-network-from-a-dem-in-qgis   Whitebox tools in QGIS has stream network analysis tools IF you have the plugin already installed.  The plugin's repository is currently unavailable.  GRASS is working for me in 3.26.  What version of QGIS and SAGA are you using?

Comment: I have been using GRASS in QGIS 3.26 on some big data sets with up to 30 hours runtime. I recommend this simple guide: https://giscrack.com/automatically-delineate-a-watershed-in-qgis/ Be aware of memory issues- e.g. default memory use needs to be increased on my system and I need to enable disk swapping. Also the program writes many files to a temporary directory, which can cause issues. Finally this free acces recent article has a good discussion of DEM processing: https://doi.org/10.1080/19475683.2019.1604571

Comment: @LeighBettenay I'm doing fantasy cartography, so my dataset is relatively small, thankfully. How do you get QGIS to use more memory? I'm running it on a rig made for video editing so I have plenty to give it. I thought it was already pulling all it could pull. It's taking advantage of all 12 cores I have.

Comment: @johns I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: @johns No dice. I'm using the latest for everything. I got it to stop crashing and tell me "cannot generate files" or some crap that it insists has an error log, but instead just tells me what python command it tried to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you use to create the streams? It seems you have some low lying areas and certain hydrology algorithms do a "fill depressions" in advance to allow routing the streams. The GRASS GIS module `r.watershed`, for example,  avoids this, using an MFD algorithm that is able to search for the "best" or "prettiest" route through low/flat areas.

Comment: I can't use r.watershed, it crashes QGIS for me every time I try. I looked into this and apparently, a lot of GRASS plugins are just broken for Windows right now. I used SAGA's Channels and Basins for this.

Comment: There is always the option to run GRASS on its own, without QGIS.

Comment: I'm trying to do that at the moment. I'm new to this. I'm not sure how exactly you do that, and cannot find a good tutorial.

Comment: Maybe some tips [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/learn/newcomers/)

Answer (score 0):

Which algorithm did you use for DEM preprocessing? I've had that issue sometimes when working with "medium-high" resolution DEM. Anyway, the problem is quiet common when analyzing flat areas. Try with SAGA the different algorithms within Terrain analysis --> preprocessing and create channels with each of them in order to see which one fits better with the actual drainage pattern. Once I had that problem and the only way to avoid the straight streams was using "sink removal" instead of "fillsinks" and then calculating channel network. Hope can be useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).